# Oracle number precision scale: ORA-01438 when loading data

Tags: sql, oracle

**My Table structure**

```
CREATE TABLE ACCT
(ACCT_NO varchar2(15),
CASH number(20,4))
```

**Current data:**

```
ACCT_NO   CASH
12        1E16
```

I get error `ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column`, when i try to insert a new record with value for `CASH` as `1E16`.

`INSERT INTO ACCT VALUES(12, 1E16)`

But it works good if i try to copy and insert the existing data as below.

```
INSERT INTO acct
select * FROM ACCT
WHERE acct=12
```

What am i hitting wrong?
I understand that precision includes scale length too i.e `NUMBER(20,4)` means 16 digits precision`.`4 digits scale. So how come there is already a data with 17 digits precision? and i face no error if i reinsert the same data?

**EDIT 1:**
`SELECT TO_CHAR(CASH) FROM ACCT` returns me `9999999999999999` (16 digits). 
But, `SELECT CASH FROM ACCT` returns `1E16`.

So, oracle is adding 1 to the existing data `9999999999999999` and displays my data as `1E16` i.e `9999999999999999+1=1E16`

There are some 3 million data in this table and the data extract i gave to my client is showing up as `1E16` instead of `9999999999999999`. A complete blindspot to unaware user.

This type of data might be available in any other table. Is there any solution so that `SELECT CASH FROM ACCT` query will display `9999999999999999` instead of `1E16`

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how did the data `1E16` get into the table in the first place?

Comment: Oracle isn't adding -- it's rounding up the value to present it in scientific notation. The default string representation of this value doesn't roundtrip, and the table can't really (and doesn't really) hold `1E16`. Obviously `9999999999999999` is being used as a sentinel value (possibly by someone who's never heard of `NULL`). I don't know if there's any way to change the number format for display used by Oracle. For client software, this *ought* not to matter since the value should be extracted with its actual type, not as whatever the query tools decide to display it as.

Comment: Actually, in the above comment I'm being unfair to Oracle -- it isn't the database engine that's doing this, but your client tools. Although you are presumably using the default client tools supplied by Oracle, this distinction is important: the table data is consistent, and it is possible to get and set it consistently.

Comment: @Vivek: You can use [TO_CHAR](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions181.htm) function with [format model](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#g195443) to display your number in your own format.

Comment: @JSapkota i understand that. There are many other tables where these kind of data might be hidden. Ignore `1E16`,  as i can always find and replace manually or using scripts. But, i see cases where `99999999999999.99` is extracted as `100000000000000`. I do not see any workaround here :( I am checking with my client if `.01` makes any real difference for them.

Comment: This is strictly a client/display issue.  This is the result of displaying via scientific notation.  You can test this and get the same issue with Excel.  If you what the exact value to display, you'll need to either convert the value to the string format you want to see, or adjust settings in your client software.  Toad has an option to display large numbers in scientific notation and it is on by default.  It also appears it is also default for sql*plus.  Know, the underlying value is not being changed, just the display value.